# Spring Boot - Return value from CompletableFuture, to be used in main calling function, while the async process is still executing

Tags: spring-boot, asynchronous, completable-future

I have a submit method where I take inputs from UI and save it in database. But I also need to execute some other processes Asynchronously in between.

My challenge is: I need a Boolean value from the response object from the @Async call to be used in the main calling function flow to perform next set of activity (calling a webservice based on true boolean value set in the response object), while this @Async will continue to execute further other process.

I am trying to use CompletableFuture to get a placeholder Boolean value of the response object, but I cannot use that reference placeholder value as I need the actual 'true' value to call some other webservice in main flow.

I am not exactly sure how I can achieve this.

I will really appreciate if anyone can suggest how to achieve that.

This is all to improve the performance of my the application flow.

Comment: Why don't you return CompletableFuture that combines both these async operations like this: CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> first operation).thenApply(firstOpResult -> second operation);

Comment: But this will become a synchronous sequential flow right?. I mean the second operation had to wait for the first operation to finish and that's what I am don't want the flow to do. I believe, the async flow needs to be independent parallel flow with the main flow in case the main flow does not require the response immediately from the async flow.